# Unix domain or TCP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sockets, unix, tcp

I have a fairly simple Rails app that connect to Postgres server (locally).

Uptil now, I was under the impression if not specified (socket in the database.yml) the pg client connect with postgres over TCP on a loopback interface.

Fyi,this is how my configuration looks like.

```
{:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :database=>"scp_development"}
```

But I think I was wrong I can't sniff any packet over the loopback interface at port 5432.

`sudo tcpdump -nnvvXSs 1514 -i lo0 dst port 5432`

Which is letting me believe that it working over Unix domain socket.

So, is there a fairly reliable way to determine ...

Whether I'm connected to TCP socket or Unix socket?

Comment: Knowing nothing of ruby on rails, I can suggest using strace. It will tell exactly what arguments have been passed to `socket()` call.

Comment: "netstat -a" can be used to show all active socket connections at any given time. Try to run it while your client is running

Comment: @SergeyA I checked with `strace` and it was `unix` socket thanks.